# HTML: How to Create Table Lines like that in this Example Table

Tags: html, html-table, border

I am attempting to use html to create a table with the exact same table lines as the example table shown below. I have found a million different approaches online (many of which seem to contradict each other). If possible, I would prefer to use only html and not css. You will notice the table has 3 table lines total with a mixture of both thick and thin lines.

[image]

Here is an example of my HTML so far. A few notes: 1) You can see in the first "tr" tag where I attempted a table line under the ANOVA heading - this currently does NOT work. 2) You will notice that I am working in an environment where the "EQN" tags are resolved by a Perl compiler.

```
<div class='indent'>
<table>
<col width="140">
<col width="80">
<col width="110">
<col width="110">
<col width="110">
<col width="110">
<tr style="border-bottom thin solid">
<th align = "left">ANOVA</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td align = "right"><em>df</em></td>
<td align = "left"><em>               SS</em></td>
<td align = "center"><em>               MS</em></td>
<td align = "center"><em>      F</em>-Statistic</td>
<td align = "center"><em>      p</em>-value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Regression</td>
<td align = "right"><EQN $k></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($SSR)></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($MSR)></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Residual</td>
<td align = "right"><EQN $dfe></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($SSE)></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($MSE)></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Total</td>
<td align = "right"><EQN $dft></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($SST)></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For reference sake, my html table currently looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone suggest code to add these table lines? Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution i built for you. I just set the border of the cell to only have a thickness on the top one the first two lines and then on the bottom for the last row and then collapsed the borders so there wouldn't be white spaces in the lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#lineAboveThick {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
#lineAboveThin {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
#lineBelowThick {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='indent'>
<table>
<col width="140">
<col width="80">
<col width="110">
<col width="110">
<col width="110">
<col width="110">
<tr style="border-bottom thin solid">
<th align = "left">ANOVA</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td id="lineAboveThick"></td>
<td id="lineAboveThick" align = "right"><em>df</em></td>
<td id="lineAboveThick" align = "left"><em>               SS</em></td>
<td id="lineAboveThick" align = "center"><em>               MS</em></td>
<td id="lineAboveThick" align = "center"><em>      F</em>-Statistic</td>
<td id="lineAboveThick" align = "center"><em>      p</em>-value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="lineAboveThin">Regression</td>
<td id="lineAboveThin" align = "right"><EQN $k></td>
<td id="lineAboveThin" align = "right"><EQN commas($SSR)></td>
<td id="lineAboveThin" align = "right"><EQN commas($MSR)></td>
<td id="lineAboveThin"></td>
<td id="lineAboveThin"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Residual</td>
<td align = "right"><EQN $dfe></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($SSE)></td>
<td align = "right"><EQN commas($MSE)></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  id="lineBelowThick">Total</td>
<td   id="lineBelowThick" align = "right"><EQN $dft></td>
<td  id="lineBelowThick" align = "right"><EQN commas($SST)></td>
<td  id="lineBelowThick"></td>
<td  id="lineBelowThick"></td>
<td  id="lineBelowThick"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body
</html>
```

Here is the css

```
#lineAboveThick {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
#lineAboveThin {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
#lineBelowThick {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```